# Firefox only saves and displays logins in Troubleshoot mode

Tags: firefox, browser, login

I have a weird problem in Firefox 94.0.

For some reason, a few days ago firefox randomly started disabling the display of logins.

When I login to a website, it'll ask me to save the username and password.

But when I go to the login page, it won't be there, and doesn't autofill next time I login;

I read a few posts on Mozilla Support, and one of them said to open in troubleshoot mode.

It did work, however, when I turn off troubleshoot mode, it does it again.

It's very strange and never happened before.

Why is it doing this?

I only have a DuckDuckGo extension, and no plugins. I tried disabling and removing the addons multiple times - that didn't do anything.

Any clue?

Comment: Did you try a full uninstall, restart, re-install of Firefox?  I have Firefox 94 on Ubuntu and it saves logins just fine. No extensions.

Comment: I'm afraid if I uninstall it, I might lose information.

Comment: That is true, but I do not know any other way to fix an app like this.

Comment: I do have a raspberry pi though that has firefox and works fine, so I could login and sync it